# How to 'get arguments for calls made on' a Mock in Pester (or otherwise generate a helpful message containing actual and expected values)?

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, mocking, pester

While there are *many* examples of using Pester to *Assert a Mock*, I am unable to find good (or any) examples on how to use Pester to get parameters made upon a Mock; this is useful to get a *meaningful error message* instead of a generic message of so-so usefulness:

> Expected Invoke-XYZ to be called at least 1 times but was called 0 times

Thanks, and obviously; might as well be a "didn't work" SO question.

In RhinoMocks + NUnit (C#), for example, one might use code similar to the following to assert that the mock was called *and* the arguments match some criteria. If the call was made and the arguments do *not* match, then a useful assertion message is displayed:

```
var actual = mock.GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn(m => ..);
Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));
```

How can the same (or similar) be done in Pester?

**The goal is to make failing mock assertions result in *useful* error messages as to *what* particular parameter failed the expectations, and with *what* value(s).**

PowerShell is 5.1 and Pester is 4.8.1.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue/question about Pester testing with parameter checks; it's always been hard to track down which parameter may have failed a given `-ParameterFilter` expression.

It's been raised in a couple of GitHub issues:

1. https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/376
2. https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/1160

But it doesn't seem like there was any resolution or consensus yet. I would try to add to the conversation there if you can.

One user talked about making a Verify function that is called within the `Assert-MockCalled` call:

```
It 'multiple expressions, second line' {
    Assert-MockCalled f 1 {
        ($a -eq 1 | Verify) -and
        ($b -eq 1 | Verify) -and
        ($b-1 -eq $a | Verify)
    }
}
```

which gave better output, but was a hacky/verbose way of getting around this.

Personally, my workaround has been to write multiple `Assert-MockCalled` statements, each with a `-ParameterFilter` expression that checks only one parameter, so that I can know which parameter failed based on which `Assert-MockCalled` statement failed. But, this approach does not work so well if, say, the mock is called multiple times within the function.